# Configure IIS to be used in an intranet with a specific IP

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-8

I work on this company where I was asked to develop a helpdesk, now the problem is that I have been asked to configure the webserver on which I will be hosting this helpdesk, internally only.

Since in this company we only use Windows, I decided to install IIS, PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin.

All of them are working flawlessly.

My boss told me that I should use the following IP to host the helpdesk:

> 192.168.0.100

I have never worked with IIS before, and if someone can help me how to assign this IP to my helpdesk I will be eternally thankful.

Additional information:

My helpdesk is already there and working flawlessly.

All I need to do know is assign the IP to IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the ip to your server is enough. IIS will listen on 0.0.0.0 (all IP addresses on the server).

If the server has more than one IP address and you want to bind only one of them, open your website in the IIS tree and select "bindings":

[image]

Comment: Ok I already assigned the IP address to my computer which is the one working as the server. The problem is that I'm not being able to access the website from any other part of the company. Not even the laptop I have right on my side.

Comment: firewall or something? :O

Comment: Maybe, I'm trying to figure out. I disabled windows firewall for now. Still doesnt work. Do I need to do some port forwarding or open ports for this to work?

Comment: Have you checked the IIS log to see if it's getting the request at all?

Comment: Just checked, they aren't being received. Is there any other configuration needed? My company uses watchguard, cisco meraki and it is divided into various vlans. Is there something else I should be doing. My boss says all ports are enabled and no port forwarding should be required.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the port in firewall on which port your app is running...

If you want to access your website then you can able to access it via it's ip address...

Forexample your webserver ip is 1.1.1.1 then you can access your application with that ip...if you want to access by it's name you need to configure that name with this ip in F5 url..or at some external sources...